ReactJs throws exception on passed in object which should be valid
What am I doing wrong here?
export function Wrapper({ json }) {
    console.log('Wrapper:', json)
    return (
        <>
        <div className="label">
            Code:
            <input
                className="editable"
                type="text"
                defaultValue={json.code}
            />
        </div>
        </>
    )
} 

This is the exception:
Wrapper.jsx:10 
 Uncaught (in promise) 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'code')
    at Wrapper (Wrapper.jsx:10:36)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27465:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26505:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26473:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25889:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26135:20)

Here I am calling the Wrapper...
        <div className="label">
          Wrapper:
          {console.log('Wrapper:', json.wrapper)}
          <Wrapper json={json.wrapper} />
        </div>



Here is the json fragment of the api call...
  "wrapper": {
    "returnType": "System.Single",
    "name": "wrapper",
    "timeStep": 0,
    "done": false,
    "fitness": 0,
    "key": null,
    "value": 65,
    "code": "(ConvertNegOnePosOne w)"
  },


Why isn't that json object I am passing valid?  I can log it and it's there.  When I try and assign it, it's not there...

It's probably due to json being null before the api call succeeds.

json.wrapper is undefined. It's hard to know from the code you shared why it is, but figuring that out will also solve this bug.

When I call console.log(...) it's there...

I can only comment on specific symtpoms because you didn't share the code that sets json.wrapper, so one can only guess.

Wrapper is just a json fragment.  Just put open and close brackets on it.

I just try your code and I don't have your problem so I have no idea how to help you. the stranger is that when I try with another inexistent key like defaultValue={json.abc}, I have no errors. give us more details about what is around like framework, cache system, etc.
